# Help with Screen Tearing in Ubuntu 14.04 with Nvidia 331.79 driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.04

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in my Lenovo Ideapad y510p which has GT 755M discrete graphics card. I installed propriety Nvidia drivers version 331.79 in Ubuntu. Now I face screen tearing while browsing, playing videos etc. I tried various solutions but nothing worked. Before Installing the drivers glxgears showed 60 fps. After installing nvidia drivers glxgears shows 17400 fps. I found vsync is not working. But there is no option to enable vsync in Nvidia X Server Settings. Someone please help me to fix it.

Comment: I have similars problems with Ideapad S410p like you can see here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2231174 did you found any help? How you install the nvidia driver?